# Advantages of JBoss JDBC Driver As Module Over Application JDBC Driver Configuration

Tags: jdbc, jboss

I would like to know the benefits of configuring JDBC Driver in JBoss As a module than package JDBC driver in application in terms of

connection pool
data source
caching
distributed environment

Please enlighten this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module datasources

1. are shareable across multiple applications.
2. integrate with all of the monitoring and management facilities of JBoss AS, such as the CLI and web console.
3. provide good integration with JBoss security domains.